# How to auto-extract or index day from timestamp in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

We have a Postgres table with a timestamp field `created_at`.  On a regular basis, we need to find all the records with the day field of `created_at` being a certain number.

We can run a query like

```
select * from table where extract(day from created_at) = 3;
```

I suspect this isn't efficient, ie it's doing a full-table scan.  If so, can I create an index somehow to make the above efficient?

If it's not possible, we can create a separate column called `created_at_day` and create an index on it.

So we can simply run the query like

```
select * from table where created_at_day = 3;
```

Let's say `created_at` can be updated.  Whenever this happens, `created_at_day` should be updated, too.

Does Postgres provide any support to automatically keep `created_at_day` in sync with `created_at`?  If so, how?

Of course this can be done in the application logic.  So whenever `created_at` is created or updated, we update the `created_at_day` column.  But just wondering if there's an easier, automated way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Don’t create a separate column. You can create an index on the extracted day

Comment: How do I do that @SamiKuhmonen ?

Comment: You can define a function instead of just column. So in the `CREATE INDEX` specify `extract(day from created_at)` as the target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index on `extract(day from created_at)`

To see the difference:

**Create a table**

```
knayak=# create table t as select i ,now()::timestamp + interval '1 days' * i as created_at from generate_series(1,10000) as i;
SELECT 10000
```

**Create normal index on created_at**

```
knayak=# create index ind_created_at on t(created_at);
CREATE INDEX

knayak=# explain analyze select * from t where extract(day from created_at) = 3;
                                           QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..205.00 rows=50 width=12) (actual time=1.049..6.020 rows=328 loops=1)
   Filter: (date_part('day'::text, created_at) = '3'::double precision)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 9672
 Planning time: 0.392 ms
 Execution time: 6.070 ms
(5 rows)
```

**Create index with extract**

```
knayak=# drop index ind_created_at;
DROP INDEX
knayak=# create index ind_created_at on t( extract(day from created_at) );
CREATE INDEX
knayak=# explain analyze select * from t where extract(day from created_at) = 3;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=4.67..61.66 rows=50 width=12) (actual time=0.110..0.260 rows=328 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (date_part('day'::text, created_at) = '3'::double precision)
   Heap Blocks: exact=54
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ind_created_at  (cost=0.00..4.66 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=0.093..0.093 rows=328 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (date_part('day'::text, created_at) = '3'::double precision)
 Planning time: 0.316 ms
 Execution time: 0.314 ms
(7 rows)
```